# SSRS cascading parameter needs a value, even though the parent field has other values

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have an ssrs report, in which the user can choose the type of the chart he needs(pie,line,.., table).if the user chooses "table", another parameter must be chosen (@ListOfColumns). if I choose "table", I can see the list of fields and generate the report. When I choose another type of chart, the list of fields is empty(as it should be),but cannot generate the report due to "@ListOfColumns" parameter needs a value.I tried to set this parameter to blank and null, but didn't work. before adding "table" and cascading parameter, everything was working fine.

detail:
@ChooseChartType parameter is integer, with "specify values":1,2,3,4(4 is table).
@ListOfColumns dataset is:

```
if(@ChooseChartType=4)

SELECT 1 ID, 'TypeOfTest' AS ColumnName UNION 

SELECT 2 ID, 'NoOfTest' AS ColumnName UNION

SELECT 3 ID, 'Priority' AS ColumnName UNION

SELECT 4 ID, 'Purpose' AS ColumnName UNION

SELECT 5 ID, 'TypeOfRoute' AS ColumnName UNION

SELECT 6 ID, 'CreatedBy' AS ColumnName
```

Answer (score 0):

Add IF conditions to your dataset then just remove @ListOfColumns from your dataset script if it's not needed.